# Grounding of one pahse of a starpoint where the point is not grounded

Tags: three-phase

Note: This is just a thought experiment.

What would be the effect on a three phased system if one phase of the star-point was grounded with no other ground connection in the system?
In other words: you have a generator generating three phase connected to a transformer with the secondary side connected in star. The star-point is floating with  regards to ground and one phase connected to ground.

With single phase loads connected to each live. All loads and components are balanced.

Update:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs2Y5l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To clarify the question: 
I see two possible outcomes: as  in @Charles Cowie answer, the circuit operates as normal as there is no other ground path.

The other possibility is that the circuit will act similar to a star-point grounded three phase circuit that 
has a phase to ground fault. The reason being that the L3 will attempt to equalize the change between it 
and the earth. Similar to what happens to the helicopter used in live wire repairs.

This equalization will fail due to the size of the earth. What I am not sure about is whether the the 
equalization of charge in the case of the helicopter and the transmission line is due to induced currents 
from the magnetic fields surrounding the transmission line or if power is being transferred from the line.

I hope this clears up the question.

Comment: A diagram would help.

Comment: GND is just an arbitrary label that we attach to a point to mean 0V and reference everything to. If you do that in a 230V system, then you basically talk about the phase to phase voltage, hence people call those systems often 400V systems.

Comment: Sims are cheap and apart from safety issues being contravened a sim will tell you all you wish to know about the voltage levels. Voting to close as unclear why this question is relevant.

Comment: If there's only one connection to ground, how much current can flow through this connection? How much effect will this current have on the rest of the circuit?

Comment: Draw a schematic and you'll see that it does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

If a power distribution system is not connected to ground, then a fault in the system that connects a point to ground will theoretically not cause any fault current to flow. There will likely be some small current because there is likely to be capacitive coupling or some other high-impedance connection to ground somewhere in the system.

If if either the neutral point of a star system or a phase of a star system is connected to ground, that defines the voltage to ground and the ground fault path impedance for the entire system. If the neutral point is grounded, the voltage to ground of each phase is the line-to-neutral voltage. If one phase is connected to ground, the other two phases will be at the phase voltage with respect to ground and the neutral point will be at the line-to-neutral voltage with respect to ground. The consequences of grounding one phase would primarily be the resulting voltages and currents in the event of a ground fault at some other point in the system.

In summary:

The effect of a ground fault is predictable with a system with a grounded neutral. With an ungrounded system, one ground fault can be un-detected, That means that the voltages with respect to ground and the consequences of a ground fault are not predictable. With one phase grounded, the effect of a ground fault is not the same everywhere in the system. If the neutral is grounded, the voltages with respect to ground is limited to the line-to-neutral voltage. Therefore a star system with a grounded neutral is preferred.